# A body falling on an inclined surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, free-body-diagram

Say, an object is falling down with the initial speed `v` on an inclined surface:

[image: body is falling]

Gravity is acting, so immediately before the impact, the object will have the velocity of `v+gΔt`:

[image: right before impact]

Now, let's assume that there is no friction and no inertia. Also, let's assume that the body is absolutely inelastic: it won't bounce, just smack against the surface and immediately roll down without friction.

Now, it is my understanding that the velocity of the ball down the slope will be equal to `(v+gΔt)×sinα`. In other words, a sinα portion of its vertical velocity will be converted into down-the-slope diagonal speed.

[image: rolling down the slope]

`(v+gΔt)×sinα` is its initial speed upon contact: the ball will also accelerate at `gsinα` due to gravity. As for the cosα portion of the pre-contact speed: it's gonna be absorbed by the impact, and the corresponding portion of kinetic energy will be converted into thermal energy, or whatever.

Am I correct so far?

Now, my understanding is that a portion of velocity has to be absorbed in the first place because on inclined surfaces, the vertical and horizontal speeds are interdependent: the slower an object moves horizontally, the slower it descends (and vice versa). In other words, the horizontal speed acts as a restrictor to how fast an object can descend: since it can only get so much horizontal speed upon impact, its vertical speed has to be capped. Reduction of vertical speed means that some energy must be dissipated.

What follows is that if an object had some horizontal speed beforehand (for example, it was thrown at an angle), it will allow it go move down the slope faster, preserve more vertical speed, and reduce the impact:

[image: falling-at-an-angle]

To calculate the down-the-slope speed upon impact and the amount of energy dissipated, I would just rotate the image and treat the combined horizontal+vertical velocity as if it was "falling" speed:

[image]

From here, I can apply `sinα` and `cosα` for the new angle and find out that indeed down-the-slope speed would be much higher compared to after straigh-down falling.

My first question is: is all of the above correct, and is there anything that I'm missing?

And now to my second question. Suppose we run the very first scenario again (straight-down falling), but this time our object will have significan inertial mass. According to my calculations, its initial down-the-slope speed upon impact should be `(v+gΔt)×sinα`. However, it shouldn't be able to generate that speed instantaneously because of inertia: the body has been falling down with pure vertical speed, but down-the-slope speed has a horizontal component that can't just pop up out of nowhere.

So, what exactly is going to happen? More kinetic energy will be dissipated into heat because the initial down-the-slope speed will be even slower than `(v+gΔt)×sinα`? And how much slower? Is there a way to calculate the dependency between the amount of dissipated energy/down-the-slope initial speed and the object's mass?

What makes me even more confused is that technically, an object that has any mass whatsoever requires SOME time to acquire any speed at all. Which means that momentarily, the object's speed upon impact must be completely reduced to zero. And yet that's not what we see with real objects: a falling something will move down the slope faster than if just put on the slope and let to be accelerated by gravity.

Maybe the horizontal inertia gets cancelled somehow by `mg×sinα` in a way that I just don't see?

Answer (score 1):

This is best understood by introducing a concept of *momentum* and *impulse*. The *impulse-momentum theorem* says

$$\boxed{\vec{p}_0 + \vec{J} = \vec{p}_1} \tag 1$$

where $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$ is the momentum of the system (object plus ramp), and $\vec{J}$ is the impulse:

$$\boxed{\vec{J} = \vec{F}_\text{net} \Delta t} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \boxed{\vec{J} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec{F}_\text{net} dt} \tag 2$$

What this means is that at the moment of impact there was some huge (but finite) force between the object and the ramp that was acting in a finite time $\Delta t$, and this force has changed the momentum of the system. Since momentum of the ramp before and after the impact remained the same (its velocity is zero), the falling object lost some of its kinetic energy to other (non-recoverable) forms of energy during the collision. In general, in an inelastic collision the kinetic energy of the system is not preserved!

**In order to quantify object's velocity after the impact**, you would need to know properties of the collision, i.e. the *collision force* profile over time. Since this force is (usually) much larger than other forces acting on the object, the collision force dominates and other forces such as gravitational or friction forces can be neglected in the calculation of impulse $\vec{J}$. See below for an example of a force during an inelastic collision.

[image: Force during inelastic collision]

<sup>Figure 1. Example of a force during an inelastic collision ([Source here](https://www.vernier.com/vernier-ideas/impulse-comparison-for-elastic-and-inelastic-collisions/))</sup>

In an elastic collision, the kinetic energy of the system is preserved. However, for a collision to be elastic, relative velocities of the two objects before and after the collision must be the same in magnitude and opposite in direction. Since ramp is at rest all the time, this means the ball should bounce vertically after the collision. Your example mandates the ball to keep moving on the ramp without bouncing, hence the collision is perfectly inelastic meaning that all energy is converted into heat and deformation of objects. The ball keeps moving on the ramps from zero velocity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your troubles will all disappear if you allow one of two things: either (1) impact is instantaneous and impact forces are infinite (of course, real forces aren’t infinite, but this model can still be a useful way to think about things) or (2) the impact occurs over some short but finite time.

In either case, assuming no friction, so that the force on the ball is perpendicular to the ramp surface, momentum in the along-ramp direction will be conserved—the velocity component in the downhill direction will not change during the impact.

So, the downhill velocity doesn’t “come from nowhere”; it was there already. And the sudden change in the velocity component perpendicular to the ramp is brought about by a large force acting for a short time, or, if you like, for conceptual purposes, an infinite force applied at a single point in time.

In the above explanation I have chosen, for simplicity, to decompose the velocity of the ball just prior to impact into components parallel and perpendicular to the ramp. The impact leaves the former unchanged and reduced the latter to zero. If you choose instead to decompose it into vertical and horizontal components, then you find that the impact force, being at an angle, changes both components of the velocity—the vertical component of the impact force slows (but does not stop) the ball’s rate of vertical descent, and the horizontal component of the impact force starts it moving to the left.

*EDIT* One further possible source of confusion is the idea that in a “completely inelastic collision” the two bodies must momentarily come to rest with respect to each other. All that is implied by “inelastic” is that no energy is stored in deformation of the bodies during the collision and then given back. So there is no “bouncing off”, but in the frictionless case there can be relative motion along the direction of the interface, and unless the impact occurs normal to the surface, there will be.

Answer (score 1):

The understanding shown in the first part of your question, about picking a frame in which you have rotated the ramp, is fine as far as it goes, but if you do rotate the ramp in that way, you need to account for the change when you consider the acceleration due to gravity. Also it makes no sense to assume 'no inertia', when you question is all about how a body moves under the influence of forces!

The mistake you have made in the second part of your question is to assume that if the object did come to a stop on impacting the ramp that the only force accelerating it subsequently would be the component of gravity down the ramp. That would be true if the collision was entirely inelastic- the body would come to a complete stop and then start to accelerate down the ramp in exactly the same way that an object placed on the ramp would accelerate. If the collision wasn't elastic, then the body would still come to a momentary halt, but its acceleration would then be the result of two forces- firstly an elastic restoring force which would cause it to rebound at an angle from the ramp and secondly the force of gravity acting down the slope of the ramp.

Comment: My understanding is that elastic collision implies bouncing off. I'm confused: is there a way for a body to be elastic but not bounce of the ramp on collision (just hit it and start rolling down, no lose of contact). Also, from your answer I understand that if an object doesn't bounce off, then it has to momentarily halt motion. So, is there any way for an object to not lose contact with the ramp after hititng it and yet preserve that sinα component of speed? Somehow repel that vertical speed of the ramp without breaking contact with it?

Comment: @Slavus Elastic collisions occur only when the forces between the colliding objects are conservative, which means *collision energy* is restored as kinetic energy. One more property of elastic collision is that relative forces before and after the collision are same in magnitude and opposite in direction. This implies the ball bounces vertically off the ramp after the collision. The situation you describe as "ball hits the ramp and continues moving without bouncing" implies inelastic collision.

Comment: @Slavus You can do this if you posit a small smooth curve that redirects the downward falling direction to the sliding direction. Think of a track similar to the [tautochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve) or [brachistochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve).

Comment: @MarkoGulin, but then I wonder: in the real world, we often see "non-bouncing" landings on ramps where at least some of the initial vertical speed is converted into speed down the slope. For example, snowboardists land on inclined surfaces and don't bounce off, and yet their speeds down the slope upon landing are clearly higher than if they just started on top of the slope and let the gravity accelerate them (even if they drop down vertically on the slope). Or if I just drop a bag of squishy meat on a ramp, it won't bounce and yet slide down faster than if just placed on the slope.

Comment: @MarkoGulin, so if I understand it correctly, the landings of both a snowboardist and a bag of meat are elastic collisions, but they don't visibly bounce off and lose contact with the surface upon collision because they change their shape upon collisions (the snowboardist bends his knees, the bag of meat gets squashed), which conceals the bounce but allows the horizontal component of velocity to be repelled. Is that correct?

Comment: @Slavus When you first drop some object it has kinetic energy $K_1$, then gravitational force does some positive work $W_g$ and just before collision the object has kinetic energy $K_2 = K_1 + W_g$. Now collision happens and takes some energy from $K_2$ such that object’s kinetic energy after collision is $K_3 = K_2 + W_c$ where $W_c < 0$. If $W_g + W_c > 0$ then $K_2 > K_3 > K_1$. Note that in elastic collision the work $W_c$ is conservative (recoverable to kinetic energy), and in inelastic collision the work $W_c$ is *lost* to other forms of energy. Your example is inelastic collision.

Comment: @MarkoGulin, but if snowboardists are inelastic collisions, why are their speeds down the slope higher after they drop down on it compared to if they just stood on it and rode down? Because Marco Ocram above wrote that if the collision is inelastic then the speed upon landing HAS to be exactly the same as if the object was just placed directly on the ramp. Yet the speed of a boardist dropping down on a slope would be higher than if she stood on the slope and rode down. So some kinetic energy (despite the impact being inelastic) has to convert into kinetic energy down the slope.

Comment: @Slavus Care to join the chat room? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133388/impulse-momentum

Comment: @slavus a degree of elasticity does not mean that the falling body has to bounce off the ramp. The falling body becomes compressed when it hits the ramp, as does the surface of the ramp near the point of collision- both become distorted. Imagine, for example, standing on the top of a table and jumping down on the ground. Your knees flex to absorb the impact, then you stand upright.

Comment: Likewise, in your second diagram where you show the point of collision you should really show the circle representing the object as being somewhat flattened, and the line representing the slope of the ramp being distorted downwards at the moment of  impact.

Comment: @MarcoOcram, I understand, but does it mean that some degree of elasticity allows to redirect some of the velocity upon hitting the ramp EVEN IF there was no visible bounce? Say, if I dropped a plush bear on a ramp, will the fact that it will deform upon impact make some of its vertical velocity redirect down the slope? Assuming that it doesn't bounce.